# Creating a security realm on WildFly 8.1.0 - Node path format is wrong around 'x' on issuing a command to create the realm

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, wildfly, java-ee-7, wildfly-8

When issuing the following command on `jboss-cli.bat` (an MS-DOS batch file for windows) to create a security realm on WildFly 8.1.0 final as mentioned in [this migration guide](http://wildfly.org/news/2014/02/06/GlassFish-to-WildFly-migration/),

```all
./subsystem=security/security-domain=app:add(cache-type="default")
  cd ./subsystem=security/security-domain=app
     ./authentication=classic:add(
       login-modules=[ {
         code="Database",
         flag="required",
         module-options={
           dsJndiName="java:/jdbc/project_datasource",
           principalsQuery="SELECT password FROM user_role_table WHERE user_id=?",
           rolesQuery="SELECT group_id, 'Roles'
                       FROM group_table gt INNER JOIN user_role_table urt ON gt.user_group_id = urt.user_id
                       WHERE urt.user_id=?", hashAlgorithm="SHA-256",
           hashEncoding="BASE64",
           unauthenticatedIdentity="guest"
         }
       }, {
         code="RoleMapping",
         flag="required",
         module-options={
           rolesProperties="file:${jboss.server.config.dir}/app.properties",
           replaceRole="false"
         }
       }
     ])
```

I get the following error on the cli prompt :

> Node path format is wrong around 'cd.' (index 67)

If `cd` is removed, then the following error is reported.

> Failed to perform read-opration-description to validate the request:
>   `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException`: Operation failed

The command is given in a contiguous text format as follows.

```all
./subsystem=security/security-domain=app:add(cache-type="default") cd ./subsystem=security/security-domain=app ./authentication=classic:add(login-modules=[ {code="Database",flag="required",module-options={dsJndiName="java:/jdbc/project_datasource",principalsQuery="SELECT password FROM user_role_table WHERE user_id=?",rolesQuery="SELECT group_id, 'Roles' FROM group_table gt INNER JOIN user_role_table urt ON gt.user_group_id = urt.user_id WHERE urt.user_id=?",hashAlgorithm="SHA-256",hashEncoding="BASE64",unauthenticatedIdentity="guest"}},{code="RoleMapping",flag="required",module-options={rolesProperties="file:${jboss.server.config.dir} /app.properties",replaceRole="false"}}])
```

What is the fix? I just do not want to copy/past the XML to the configuration file as it might be different from version to version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with combining more commands on a single line.

The simple solution for you is to use external file to store the CLI commands.

E.g. create `security-domain.cli` file in `wildfly-8.1.0.Final/bin` folder with following content (if you want to split a command to more lines, put backslash as a last character):

```
/subsystem=security/security-domain=app:add(cache-type="default")
/subsystem=security/security-domain=app/authentication=classic:add()
/subsystem=security/security-domain=app/authentication=classic/login-module=Database:add( \
    code="Database", \
    flag="required", \
    module-options=[ \
        ("dsJndiName"=>"java:/jdbc/project_datasource"), \
        ("principalsQuery"=>"SELECT password FROM user_role_table WHERE user_id=?"), \
        ("rolesQuery"=>"SELECT group_id, 'Roles' FROM group_table gt INNER JOIN user_role_table urt ON gt.user_group_id = urt.user_id WHERE urt.user_id=?"), \
        ("hashAlgorithm"=>"SHA-256"), \
        ("hashEncoding"=>"BASE64"), \
        ("unauthenticatedIdentity"=>"guest") \
    ])
/subsystem=security/security-domain=app/authentication=classic/login-module=RoleMapping:add( \
    code="RoleMapping", \
    flag="required", \
    module-options=[ \
        ("rolesProperties"=>"file:${jboss.server.config.dir}/app.properties"), \
        ("replaceRole"=>"false") \
    ])
```

(Your sample contains old style of setting login modules. It's a deprecated way now, so the example usage the new way.)

Run the new file with JBoss CLI tool:

```
jboss-cli.bat -c --file=security-domain.cli
```

Comment: Thank you. This command, `jboss-cli.bat -c --file=security-domain.cli` does not run on `jboss-cli.bat` prompt after creating the `security-domain.cli` file in the `wildfly-8.1.0.Final/bin folder`. Is JBoss CLI tool something that is to be installed separately?

Comment: The JBoss CLI tool is what you start by `jboss-cli.bat`.

Comment: You don't need to start it in the interactive mode. Just start the given command from standard windows command line (e.g. cmd.exe). The `-c` argument automatically connects to WildFly and the `--file=` sets path to file with commands to run.